# How to expand and narrow base type of image in OpenCV?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

How to change **base type** (*not* # of channels) **of image** in OpenCV? E.g. convert `CV_8UC1` to `CV_32SC1` and vice versa?

Note: the objective is to *overcome type overflow* during computations and not to display expanded image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [convertTo](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-convertto) method for this:

> Converts an array to another data type with optional scaling.

Comment: For some reason I can't get it working. I use the following test: `Mat a, b; a = imread("/path/to/img"); a.convertTo(b, CV_32S); if (b.type() == CV_32S) cout << "TRUE"; else cout << "FALSE";`. And the result is "FALSE", that is, matrix `b` doesn't have supposed type `CV_32S`. Moreover, its type is not equal to those of matrix `a`. So what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I found out that `convertTo` always creates 3 channels, regrdless of `C` component of given type. Is there a way to keep # of channels unchanged?

Comment: Does it work if you add C1 to the end of the type, signifying 1 channel? For example try converting to `CV_32SC1`. You can also force `imread` to load a grayscale image by adding the flag 0: `imread("/path/to/img", 0);`

Comment: @Chris: adding `C1` doesn't help, as well as using `cvtColor` to convert already loaded image with 3 channels into grayscale single channel image. However, adding `0` to `imread` worked perfectly - after it `convertTo` method converts matrix just to what I need. I have already accepted Astor's answer, since it (mostly) covers question, but if you post your comment as a separate answer, I will be pleased to upvote it.

Comment: @ffriend No problem, glad you found a solution.